# Stop all recording apps during call Android

Tags: android, performance

I am creating an app which stops Call Recording apps if there are any during an ongoing call. I am killing all the process when a call is ongoing using below code.

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
            PackageManager pm;
            pm = getPackageManager();
            //get a list of installed apps.
            packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

            String myPackage = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
            for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
                if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;

                if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(myPackage)) continue;

                Log.e("Process Name:", packageInfo.packageName);
                mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);
            }
```

But above code kills only processes of running apps and not services. I want to stop all the apps so that whenever any call is in progress, recording is not done by any call recorder apps.
Please help and thanks in advance.